# How do I remove the head of dollar sign on stdin line in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How do I remove the head of dollar sign on stdin line in shell?
I'm always removing the dollar sign of head from a copied text.
How can I remove the $ of head?

I tried to set $ as an alias, but it's invalid, because $ is a special character.

Before:

```sh
$ $ echo 1
bash: $: command not found
```

After:

```sh
$ $ echo 1
1
```

Comment: Why not just copy two characters less ? Or press pos1 and del twice before hitting enter ?!?

Comment: Sorry, I'm lazy.

Comment: You only have to press del once; the leading space won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tagged your question `zsh`, and `$` is a valid alias name there:

```
$ echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.7.1
$ alias '$'=''
$ $ echo foo
foo
```

Comment: Thanks!  


I'll use that in zsh:DD  
And is there a valid alias or something in bash?

Comment: It's a valid command name so you can add a binary to your path, or have command_not_found_handle interpret it if you want it to work with builtins

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but add

```
bind '"$ ":""'
```

to your `.bashrc`. This will define a macro which replaces `$` with a null string when you type it (including if you paste into the terminal).

This could cause some false positives, as typing something like `echo $ hi` will also be seen as `echo hi`. However, when you first type the `$`, Readline will pause briefly to see if the next key you press is the space bar. Once the `$` actually appears on the screen, that is the sign that Readline has stopped waiting for the macro to be completed and you can type a literal space to proceed.